# ClickListener for items in a gridview in app widget

Tags: android, gridview, android-appwidget, remoteview

I want a gridview layout in widget and i am successful in making it with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603838/gridview-in-android-widgets). But i am stuck at a point where i want click to each and every item in the gridview. I searched for the solution but didn't came up with the solution. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!